# Galen framework for raw image comparison

Tags: java, android, appium, galen

Going through the below video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bheFQfEGR6U

It is seen that image embedded inside html page is went through the image comparison, it resulted out the number of pixels doesnt match.

Is there any way such that raw images are compared to expected images via galen framework

I want to compare screen captured on android device to the expected images shared by the designer ?

Answer (score 2):

you can add your own images for comparison, see http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-galen-spec-language-guide/#Image